# how can we get the attention scores of multimodal models via hugging face library?

Tags: image-processing, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model, attention-model

I was wondering if we could get the attention scores of any multimodal model using the api provided  by the hugging face library, as it's relatively easier to get such scores of normal language bert model, but what about lxmert? If anyone can answer this, it would help the understanding of such models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is true for all of the models, but most including LXMERT of them support the parameter [output_attentions](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/lxmert#transformers.LxmertModel.forward.output_attentions).

Example with CLIP:

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests
from transformers import CLIPProcessor, CLIPModel

model = CLIPModel.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")
processor = CLIPProcessor.from_pretrained("openai/clip-vit-base-patch32")

url = "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

inputs = processor(
    text=["a photo of a cat", "a photo of a dog"], images=image, return_tensors="pt", padding=True
)

outputs = model(**inputs, output_attentions=True)
print(outputs.keys())
print(outputs.text_model_output.keys())
print(outputs.vision_model_output.keys())
```

Output:

```
odict_keys(['logits_per_image', 'logits_per_text', 'text_embeds', 'image_embeds', 'text_model_output', 'vision_model_output'])
odict_keys(['last_hidden_state', 'pooler_output', 'attentions'])
odict_keys(['last_hidden_state', 'pooler_output', 'attentions'])
```

Comment: it might sound a little naive, but if there are more examples, we have to create a dataloader if i am not wrong (do the results vary? most probably they shouldn't, right?)?

Comment: The results at interference do not vary (for CLIP). A dataloader is just an iterator with a ton of convenience functions, you can also use any other data structure to hold your data.